# Difference in action between IBAction & normal program call iOS

Tags: ios

I observe a few times already there's difference in action between hitting a UIButton and call the

```
  -(IBAction) action:(id)sender     Method1
  {
    do something....
   }
```

Versus calling it programmatically  Method2

```
  -(void) action
   {
    do something....
   }
```

Method1 is correct when the action got called like that. Method2 displayed different and wrong effect.

Inside of both routine, the do something is exactly the same.

Why such difference? and what I can do to imitate the IBAction programmatically?

Comment: This shouldn't be so.  Can you provide an example where one behaves different from the other?

Answer (score 2):

`IBAction` is just a tag for Interface Builder to be able to locate actions you intend to connect to UI element actions. It is, in fact, a synonym for `void`:

#define IBAction void

Beyond that, you have 2 different method signatures. One takes an argument, one doesn't. In the method that takes an argument, `sender` will be a pointer to the UI element that triggered the action -- something you defined as an `IBOutlet` most likely.

If you have a method that is going to be invoked as the result of a UI interaction (a touch, for example), then the method signature needs to allow for the sender argument.

The argument-less method signature is useful in some situations where the object triggering the action doesn't necessarily have to be included in the method call. But you have to be consistent; if the method expects an argument, then you have to ensure that the SDK knows to send an argument. This can be as simple as including or excluding a colon (:) in the name of the selector. Gesture Recognizers are a good example. You could define an action for a gesture recognizer like this:

```
-(void)handleTap
{
    ...
}
```

and then setup the gesture recognizer to use this method:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
```

Notice the lack of a colon in `@selector(handleTap)`. On the other hand, if you had defined the methods like this:

```
-(void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRegognizer *)tap
{
    ...
}
```

You would have to create the gesture recognizer like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

See the difference? And in so doing, when the gesture recognizer calls your method, it will pass itself as the argument to your method.

Honestly, I am not sure if this nuance applys everywhere where you can specify a selector. I think it is context specific. For example, selectors for NSTimer's must be able to accept a pointer to the NSTimer object in its arguments. The documentation usually is clear about this on a case by case basis.